# How to sort the functions in a Package?

Tags: functions, packages, customization

Once a Package like 
`` abc` `` has been installed, we can use  "`` ?abc`* ``" to scan all the functions defined in this Package. Now I write a Package(`` abc` ``). After I have installed it, I use `` ?abc`* `` to scan the functions. But the function list is out-of-order. How can I set the function list to alphabetical order using `` ?abc`* `` ?

Comment: Have you tried to input the functions in your package in alphabetical order?

Comment: @eldo yes, I just do like this. but there is no effect.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to modify the ordering of Information[]; the output is a side-effect(so things like `Sort` wouldn't work on it even if the output was sortable), though I've always seen it come back in sorted order(though note it's done according to `Sort`'s ordering convention).

Comment: Did you use lowercase function names? I saw  ? "abc`*" and did you define function::usage

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  Please see my updated answer for what I feel is a much better solution than the first one I posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Description

- `?` at the beginning of a line is the short from of [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Information.html).
- Given a pattern that matches multiple Symbols `Information` returns a list of them in alphabetical (canonical) order, in columns top to bottom and left to right.  You are therefore asking how you can modify the behavior of this System function.
- You would need some way of storing the order that you wish to have these Symbol links displayed in.

### Observations

The documentation for [`Names`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Names.html) says:

> - `Names["string"]` gives the same list of names as `?string`.

In fact testing indicates that `Names` is directly used by `Information` to retrieve the list of Symbol names:

```
Block[
 {Names = {"Plus", "Times", "Divide"} &},
 Information["IAmABanana`*"]
]
```

[image]

We see that the Symbol links returned can be changed by manipulating `Names`, but we also see that the ordering remains so it is separate from `Names` functionality.  Looking for a `Sort` operation with [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TracePrint.html) reveals only one call:

```
TracePrint[
  Block[{Names = {"Plus", "Times", "Divide"} &}, Information["IAmABanana`*"]];,
  _Sort
]
```

> ```
> Sort[{{Plus,System`},{Times,System`},{Divide,System`}},System`Dump`orderfun]
> ```

It seems logical that if we can replace `` System`Dump`orderfun `` we should control the output order of `Information`.  (`Sort` is used by other internal functions during the call so we cannot `Block` it.)

### Solution

A robust approach is to create specific ordering rules for the `` System`Dump`orderfun `` function as this will allow custom ordering of even partial results.

The implementation is complex enough to justify a function to set the needed definitions:

```
addSymbolOrdering[context_String, names : {__String}] :=
  With[{pos = PositionIndex[names]},
    PrependTo[DownValues[System`Dump`orderfun],
      HoldPattern[System`Dump`orderfun[{a_, context}, {b_, context}]] :> 
        OrderedQ[pos /@ {a, b}]
    ];
  ]
```

Example of use:

```
addSymbolOrdering["foo`", {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}]
```

Context symbols may be defined before or after that use.

```
foo`one; foo`two; foo`three; foo`four; foo`five; foo`bar;
```

Note that an additional Symbol, `bar`, is included here but not in the ordering list.  This is to demonstrate that additional (or missing) names do not cause error; they will be placed at the end, though that could be changed if desired.

Example:

```
?foo`*
```

[image]

You will also find that `` ?foo`t* `` or `` ?foo`f* `` will produce the correct output, with only the matching names listed and in the correct order.

Additionally because we are setting rules on the ordering function that is used for all calls to `Information` this order will be used even for mixed results.  (For this example make sure that you do not still have the definition from **Solution 1** loaded.)

```
abc`one; abc`two; abc`three; abc`four; (* same names in a different context *)

?@@@`t*
```

[image]

Note that the custom ordering only affects the Symbol names in the specified context; those in `` abc` `` are returned in alphabetical order.