# How to prevent front end from suggesting Symbol option names (when actually String), and from adding them to Global` context

Tags: options, customization, syntax-highlighting, autocomplete

Help!

I am writing a package with a function which takes lots and *lots* of different options which are `String`s.  When used, the front end autocompletion is suggesting them in `Symbol` form.  If the resulting code is run, it is added to the `` General` `` context.  Observe:

Define the `Options` of `MyFunc`, and its `SyntaxInformation`

```
Options[MyFunc] = {"MyOpt" -> True};
SyntaxInformation[MyFunc] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}};
```

Then, start typing `MyFunc[3.2, My`, and you will see `MyOpt` as a suggestion:

[image]

If you run the finished statement `MyFunc[3.2, MyOpt->False]`, the program works as if it had been a `String` (*totally unacceptable*), **and** the option symbol `MyOpt` is added to the `` Global` `` context (*also totally unacceptable*):

[image]

This leads to a proliferation of these symbols in the user's front end, which is annoying.  How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use undocumented `"OptionNames"` property of `SyntaxInformation` to customize option names suggestions (and [coloring of invalid option names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98478/14303)).

```
MyFunc // ClearAll
MyFunc // Options = {"MyOpt" -> True};
MyFunc // SyntaxInformation = {
    "ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]},
    "OptionNames" -> {"\"MyOpt\""}
};
```

After typing `MyFunc[3.2, My` I get (in version 11.0):

[image: Auto-completion suggestions screen-shot]

Comment: Much nicer solution that mine. :-)  Any idea why ``FE`OC`` doesn't seem to be used here?  Is there another mechanism you are aware of?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No idea, sorry. Your answer here is my first contact with ``FE`OC``.

Comment: @jkuczm On my computer I'm finding that if I set `SyntaxInformation` for a function to take only options as in `"ArgumentsPattern" -> { OptionsPattern[]}`, then the front end fails to suggest a list of possible options.  Is this happening on your computer too?

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, it starts suggestions from second argument of `MyFunc`, even if according to `"ArgumentsPattern"` it should start from first. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

By convention option names are Symbols, and String equivalents are accepted.

For example all the formal [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html) of [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) are Symbols:

```
Head /@ First /@ Options[Plot] // Tally
```

> ```
> {{Symbol, 60}}
> ```

Yet you can give options as Strings as well:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, "PlotStyle" -> Red, "Frame" -> True,
  "Axes" -> False, "PlotLabel" -> "This is a plot"]
```

[image]

What you want therefore appears to go against the intentional design of *Mathematica*.

You may need to specifically interfere with that design to achieve your goal.  I thought it would be possible to do this by modifying Front End function `` FE`OC `` but changing that doesn't seem to have an effect; I suspect a different function is now used to populate these menus, but I cannot find it.

---

With modification of `` FE`OC `` not working as hoped, and remembering [Prompt a set of possible options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78935/121) it occurred to me that pre-escaping a String option name might work, and indeed it does!  Well, sort of.

```
Options[MyFunc] = {"\"MyOpt\"" -> True};

SyntaxInformation[MyFunc] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}};

MyFunc[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := {x, OptionValue["MyOpt"]}

MyFunc[foo, MyO]  (* while typing in MyO *)
```

[image]

Selecting this does actually produce a String option name.  However running it give an error:

```
MyFunc[foo, "MyOpt" -> bar]
```

> OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option MyOpt for MyFunc. >>
>
> ```
> {foo, bar}
> ```

So [`OptionValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html) doesn't like this, but it still extracts the option value correctly.  It does not however handle the default case:

```
MyFunc[foo]
```

> OptionValue::optnf: Option name MyOpt not found in defaults for MyFunc. >>
>
> ```
> {foo, "MyOpt"}
> ```

I think therefore that you may need to avoid OptionValue and write your own filter.

You will also need to deal with adding or modifying the Options list, as

```
SetOptions[MyFunc, "MyOpt" -> False]
```

> SetOptions::optnf: MyOpt is not a known option for MyFunc. >>

Before you pursue this further I think you should consider if you really have good reason to deviate from the existing design of *Mathematica* and all the headache that might entail.

---

Would modifying the list of Symbols returned by `?` be of any use to use?  See e.g.

- [How to sort the functions in a Package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57717/121)

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer!  One thing that strikes me as a little inconsistent is "by convention all option names are Symbols, and String equivalents are accepted."  This seems to run counter to what @Szabolcs [said here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22231/2048): "...to avoid cluttering the name space".  Do you rekon he is wrong?

Comment: @QuantumDot No, I don't think he is wrong.  Most of the *old* functions I am most familiar with are like `Plot`, using Symbol option names, but indeed (some) newer functions that I use less have String option names.  I guess this is inconsistency in the design itself, and the auto-completion code was probably written by someone used to the old convention as I was.