# Why does SyntaxInformation "ColorEqualSigns" color like wrong options?

Tags: options, syntax-highlighting

In my copy of *Mathematica* 11.1,

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ColorEqualSigns" -> {1, 1}}
```

colors like wrong options:

[image]

How do I make it not color like wrong options?

Comment: So `Options[f] = {myOption->..., mySecondOption->...}` is not an answer?

Comment: @Kuba Well, actually my function `f` actually takes bunch of arbitrary rules as its argument.  While syntactically equivalent to options, there isn't a finite set of possibilities for the lhs of the rules.

Comment: Why not pass your function a list of rules instead of individual rules as parameters?

Comment: @Edmund That's not a bad idea; but sometimes if there is only one rule to pass, it's more convenient to just provide the rule without enclosing it in a list.

Comment: Simply write your function to operate on a list of rules. Why would it matter if here was only one item in the list?

Comment: @Edmund This is just a matter of convenience for the end user.  Most of the time, only one rule needs to be passed to `f`, and it is easier for the user to call `f[my->rule]` than `f[{my->rule}]`.

Comment: Details for SyntaxInformations says "f the setting for "ArgumentsPattern" specifies that f takes options, then valid option names are determined from Options[f]." - it is not the case so the coloring is at least unexpected. I'd report that. I decided to not care about `SyntaxInformation` it is clearly outdated and useful for very simple cases, a subset of what its documentation suggests it can be used for. Pity but what can we do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I remembered running into this while answering an old `SyntaxInformation` based question, but here's a more systematic way to get at it.

*Note that this has been pointed out on the StackExchange both [by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140912/38205), [by jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152096/38205) [answering pretty much this exact question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98478/38205), and [by Jacob Akkerboom](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98536/38205) citing jkuczm.*

We can get all of the standard `SyntaxInformation` patterns like so:

```
siData =
  ToExpression[
     Names["*"],
     StandardForm,
     Function[Null,
      If[Length[Quiet[OwnValues[#]]] === 0 && ! 
         System`Private`HasOwnCodeQ[#],
       Thread[ToString[Unevaluated[#]] -> Keys@SyntaxInformation[#]],
       {}
       ],
      HoldAllComplete
      ]
     ] // Flatten // GroupBy[Last -> First];
```

Then look at the keys:

```
siData // Keys

{"ArgumentsPattern", "LocalVariables", "ColorEqualSigns", \
"OptionNames"}
```

And we see that curious, undocumented `"OptionNames"` thing.

We can see what functions have that:

```
withOpsNames = siData["OptionNames"]

{"CDFDeploy", "Cell", "ChoiceDialog", "CoefficientArrays", \
"CopyFile", "CreateDialog", "CreateDocument", "CreateNotebook", \
"CreatePalette", "CreateScheduledTask", "CreateWindow", \
"DefineInputStreamMethod", "DialogInput", "DialogNotebook", \
"DirectedEdges", "DocumentNotebook", "DumpSave", "Dynamic", \
"DynamicBox", "DynamicModuleBox", "DynamicWrapper", \
"DynamicWrapperBox", "ExpressionCell", "GraphAssortativity", \
"GroebnerBasis", "Input", "InputString", "LibraryFunctionLoad", \
"MessageDialog", "Notebook", "NotebookPut", "NotebookRead", \
"Notebooks", "PaletteNotebook", "PopupWindow", "Printout3D", \
"Rasterize", "ResetScheduledTask", "RunScheduledTask", "Style", \
"StyleBox", "SystemOpen", "TextCell", "URLBuild", "URLFetch", \
"URLFetchAsynchronous", "URLParse", "URLQueryDecode", \
"URLQueryEncode", "URLResponseTime", "URLSave", \
"URLSaveAsynchronous", "WaitAsynchronousTask", "WhenEvent", \
"$FrontEndSession"}
```

And then just for fun we'll find those options that are in the syntax info, but aren't in the basic `Options` list and vice versa:

```
opsNamesComplement =
  Block[{
    $Context = "Global`",
    $ContextPath = {"BoxForm`", "System`", "Global`"}
    },
   AssociationThread[
    withOpsNames ->
     ToExpression[withOpsNames, StandardForm,
      {
        Complement[Keys@Options[#], 
         ToExpression@Lookup[SyntaxInformation[#], "OptionNames", {}]],
        Complement[
         ToExpression@
          Lookup[SyntaxInformation[#], "OptionNames", {}],
         Keys@Options[#]
         ]
        } &
      ]
    ]
   ];
```

And here's some fun stuff from there:

```
Select[opsNamesComplement, 
 Length@#[[2]] > 0 && Length@Flatten@# < 10 &]

<|"Cell" -> {{Clickable, FillForm, Name, 
    VariableChangesAreEdits}, {BoxForm`Clickable, BoxForm`FillForm, 
    BoxForm`Name, BoxForm`VariableChangesAreEdits}}, 
 "CopyFile" -> {{OverwriteTarget}, {"MIMEType", Automatic}}, 
 "NotebookRead" -> {{CellContext}, {"WrapBoxesWithBoxData"}}, 
 "StyleBox" -> {{Clickable, FillForm, 
    VariableChangesAreEdits}, {BoxForm`Clickable, BoxForm`FillForm, 
    BoxForm`VariableChangesAreEdits}}|>
```

Which pops out, e.g., `"MIMType"` for `CopyFile` (an option I use all the time to make things auto-downloading in the cloud).

And note, too, what the standard `CopyFile` sytax info is:

```
SyntaxInformation[CopyFile]

{"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, OptionsPattern[]}, 
 "OptionNames" -> {Automatic, "\"MIMEType\""}}
```

Which I think shows us a way to prevent that red coloring (I'm gonna bet the `Automatic` is just inheriting the base options):

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {
  "ColorEqualSigns" -> {1, 1},
  "OptionNames" -> {Automatic, "Option1", "Option2", "Option3"}
  }
```

[image: no red]

So if you know the *potential* names of the options, you don't need to set `Options` at all. If you don't know the potential names and have no way of guessing them... Well then we have a problem.

Comment: Quite excellent. Please mark my question as a duplicate for sure.